# ¿Cómo darle formato a una fecha en fullcalendar v4?

Tags: php, fullcalendar

Hola tengo un problema en `fullcalendar` necesito una sugerencia de como se le da formato a una fecha en el evento `eventclick`, ya vi la documentación y he estado intentado diversas formas pero no me dan resultado

Con este código recupero la fecha en un alert pero con este formato:

```
Event: Thu Jul 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central)



eventClick: function(info){    
       $("#fecha_final1").val(moment(info.event.end).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));   

       },
```

Y necesito que se muestre de esta manera:

```
2019-07-04
```

Comment: de hecho si lo estaba utilizando pero no se por que aun así no me da el formato, me podrías dar un ejemplo de sintaxis del código como quedaría para dar el formato que necesito por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la opción de utilizar **[momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)** con el cual puedes dar el formato que deseas a una fecha de esta manera

```js
const getDate = () => alert(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="getDate()">Obtener fecha</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

De lo contrario si sólo estas utilizando JavaScript podrías concatenar las funciones de obtener año, mes y día

```
`${new Date().getDate()}-${(new Date().getMonth() + 1)}-${new Date().getFullYear()}`;
```

Nos comentas si te sirve

Comment: alert('Event: ' + moment(info.event.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));

Comment: Recuerda que si vas a usar momentjs debes agregar la libreria correspondiente

Comment: puse así mi código, la verdad no se como combinar fullcalendar con moment , pero ahora ya no muestra el alert

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar-4.2.0/packages/moment/main.min.js"></script>

Comment: fullcalendar cuenta con la libreria moment que corresponde a lo que me indicas no ?

Comment: Edito la respuesta y te pongo un ejemplo más practico, dame un minuto

Comment: Editada! Según lo que me indicas estas incluyendo una libreria erronea, ya que la libreria correcta es **moment.min.js** no **main.min.js**; además de eso revisa la consola (F12) para revisar si esta lanzadote algún error adicional

Comment: ya quedo ya me muestra la fecha con el formato correcto en un alert y lo paso a un input correctamente pero por que al cambiar a un input date no la muestra ? ya edite mi código en la parte de arriba de manera que ya me muestra la fecha

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96358/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-jasiel-torres).

Comment: Cambia el formato de moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY') a moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: listo ya quedo resuelto muchas gracias por tu apoyo